# When going back in history, images are not loading in meteor

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze

Today I have seen a weird behavior in my meteor app.

I have a static page on `/` with images (loaded from `/public/img`), everything works fine when I load `/` directly.

When I click the back button of my browser, it
goes back to `/` but none of the images are loaded, and broken image icon are displayed.

Has anyone encountered this error before?
I don't understand why... There is subscription, no loading...

Thanks

Comment: Are you using iron-router?

Comment: yes.
and also added `fast-render`

Comment: Did you ever find a solution? I'm facing the same issue